# No class definition found error using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

It's the first time I'm trying Hibernate Framework the XML way and I'm getting the following exception for no obvious reason.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

It's a Maven project and I've placed all my xml files on the resources directory. Is something wrong with my configuration files?

---

**hibernate.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb</property>
    <property name="connection.username">me</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>

    <mapping resource="order.hbm.xml"/>
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

**order.hbm.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="com.company.Entities.Order" table="order">
    <id name="id" type = "int" column = "oid">
        <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" column="name" type="string" />

</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

**Main**

```
public class MainApplication
{
static Session sessionObj;
static SessionFactory sessionFactoryObj;

private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory()
{
    Configuration configObj = new Configuration();
    configObj.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");

    ServiceRegistry serviceRegistryObj = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(configObj.getProperties()).build();

    sessionFactoryObj = configObj.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistryObj);
    return sessionFactoryObj;
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Order o = new Order();
    //o.setId(1);
    o.setName("first order name");

    sessionObj = buildSessionFactory().openSession();
    sessionObj.beginTransaction();

    sessionObj.save(o);
    sessionObj.getTransaction().commit();

    if(sessionObj != null)
    {
        sessionObj.close();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Which JDK version do you use? Do you use a dependencies management tools like maven ?

Comment: @wargre I use JDK 9 version. It's Maven project I've already mentioned it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you use JDK9. jaxb is not anymore in this JDK since version 9.  You have to set it on your dependencies something like :

```
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
          </dependency>
```

Comment: I added these dependencies. I'm getting a different error.
" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity "

Comment: It is another error. anyway just build your session factory with: `return new Configuration().configure("hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();`